# Find the URL values through regex

Tags: regex

I am writing one regex for fetching url from the file.

```
Regex UrlRegex = new Regex(@"url\(((..)?(\/[^)]+))\)");
```

This regex fetch the below value from my file

```
url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot?#iefix)
```

but I have to ignore "?#iefix" values and need the value like below

```
url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot)
```

Can any one suggest?

Comment: What do you want? To match `url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot` or to match `url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot)` without matching when `url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot?#anything)`?

Comment: I want to match url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot)

Comment: Do you not have a text sample of what kinds of strings you're tying to match it against?

even URLs have some variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot)`, add a `?` to your stop condition `[^)]`: `[^)?]`. This will make it consume everything until it finds a `)` or, now, a `?`.

Finally, yo get the `?#iefix` value in 4th group, use the expression:

```
url\(((..)?(\/[^?]+)(\?[^)]+)?)\)
```

See **[online demo here](http://scriptular.com/#url%5C%28%28%28..%29?%28%5C/%5B%5E?%5D%2b%29%28%5C?%5B%5E%29%5D%2b%29?%29%5C%29%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22url%28/fonts/lr-icons.eot?#iefix%29%22,%22url%28/fonts/lr-icons.eot%29%22,%22%22%5D)**. In that expression, if there is a `?something` it will be present in the 4th group.

Also, notice those `(..)?` are not matching two dots. They are matching two any characters. Make sure that's what you want. If, instead, you want it to match two dots only, you should escape them: `(\.\.)?`.

Comment: Sorry mate, its not working, actually now its is not searching "url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot" value from my file. my file is having url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot?#iefix) but i need only url(/fonts/lr-icons.eot

Comment: So you want a partial match? Please confirm that, I thought you meant something else.

Comment: Actually, i need this value in 4 group, currently, we are getting values in 3 groups,  I want to "?#iefix" value in 4th group.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer with a new expression. Check it out.